# How can I say if a number is natural return true?

Tags: python

How can I write "if the number is natural return true"? I

Ive tried with the commands int and float but it doesnt helpme

```
def perfectsquareroot(a):
 import math 
 x=math.sqrt(a)
 if x is int
     return True
 else
     return False
```

I expect false to return if the result of the square root is not a natural number

Comment: Try `int(x) == x`!

Comment: `x is int` asks if the object referred to by `x` **is** the same object referred to by `int` (which is the built-in class). That is not what you want. Note, the mathematical notion of a "natural number" is really an orthogonal concept to the *concrete numeric data structures* implemented by `float` and `int`

Answer (score 2):

```
def perfectsquareroot(a):
    import math 
    x=math.sqrt(a)
    return x == int(x)
```

Comment: Just `return x == xx`

Answer (score 1):

> Syntax of math.sqrt() method:
>
> ```
>  math.sqrt(n)
> ```
>
> Parameter(s): n – a number whose square root needs to be calculated.
>
> Return value: **float** – it returns a float value that is the square
>   root of given number n.

math.sqrt is returning float number, what means that you can't just check if the result is an integer,because it will never be.

```
import math
def perfectsquareroot(a):
     x = math.sqrt(a)
     if x%1 == 0 and x >= 0 :
         return True
     else:
         return False

print (perfectsquareroot(4))
```

output:

```
True
```

or:

```
import math
def perfectsquareroot(a):
     x = math.sqrt(a)
     if int(x) == x  and x >= 0:
         return True
     else:
         return False

print (perfectsquareroot(4))
```

output:

True